# When I type "gedit .bash_aliases" I get an empty page

Tags: bash, gedit

I am new to Ubuntu and to Linux.

When I type

```
gedit .bash_aliases
```

or

```
gedit .bash_history
```

it shows only a blank page. It doesn't write anything there. I wanted to add some aliases there and to see history of my commands. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I believe `.bash_aliases` is empty by default.

Be sure you are using

```
gedit ~/.bash_history
```

and

```
gedit ~/.bash_aliases
```

Add in the aliases you wish and save the file